# How to populate my tableview with a mutablearray from json

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

So I'm fetching data from a url which is in a json format.  I'm trying to display the data in my tableview but, even though it feels simple, I can't figure out how to do it.

```
class CompanyModel {

func getJSON() {

    let companyArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/Companies/JSON.php")!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")

            do{

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)



                if let companies = json["companies"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

                    for company in companies {

                        if let name = company["name"] as? String,
                            let phoneNumber = company["phone_number"] as? String,
                            let website = company["website"] as? String,
                            let email = company["email"] as? String,
                            let address = company["address"] as? String

                        {
                        let company = CompanyModel()

                            company.name = name
                            company.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
                            company.website = website
                            company.email = email
                            company.address = address
                        }
                        companyArray.addObject(company)
                        print(companyArray)
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }

        }
        print(companyArray) <- array is populated
    }
    print(companyArray) <- array is empty
    task.resume()
}
}
```

I know i've done it before....I'm guessing in `viewDidLoad()` I'd call `CompanyModel().getJSON()` which would fetch the data, then store it in an empty array but my mind feels blank on how to do it.

I can't declare a variable of NSarray and store the data of it the variable directly for me to then populate the tableview. Nevertheless, I hope this explains what I'm trying to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

Well first change the function to return your company array :

```
func getJSON() -> NSMutableArray {

}
```

By the end of the for loop return the company array

```
for company in companies {

 }
```

After your array is populated, return the array inside this block:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 

    return companyArray

})
```

And after `task.resume()` return the array:

```
return companyArray
```

From anywhere you wanna call this class and get the array :

Get a reference of the class

```
Let companyModal = CompanyModel()
```

And in anywhere you have your table view and the class let's say in `viewDidLoad`, you should first have `NSMutableArray`.

```
var arraySource = NSMutableArray()
```

And in `viewDidLoad` :

```
arraySource = companyModal.getJSON()
```

And to show the data in tableView do :

```
Mytableview.reloadData()
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after but for some reason my `var arraySource = NSMutableArray()` is empty.  If i do `print(companyArray)` inside the same bracket as `task.resume()` then `companyArray` is empty. Nevertheless, if i print one bracket before, it prints the full array for some reason.  not sure why the array is deleted

Comment: @luke try to define your array after func getJSON : `let companyArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()` that's I think because your array is defined in that specific brackets so after execution when the compiler finish that block , it removes all the array from memory !

Comment: I actually already did in my code - just edited the question (i think thats what you mean).  I've also added where the the print statement does and doesnt work.

Comment: @luke well ! Just return the array as soon as it's populated with all the data ! That's all what you need !

Comment: I can't return the array where it is populated as i get a compiler error, only when it isn't populated

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `return` within the closure of an asynchronous network request, you have to use a callback instead.

You need a NSMutableArray from the request, so first, let's make a callback for this:

```
completion: (array: NSMutableArray)->()
```

We add this callback to the method signature:

```
func getJSON(completion: (array: NSMutableArray)->())
```

And then *at the location where the array will be available*, we place this completion handler:

```
class CompanyModel {
    func getJSON(completion: (array: NSMutableArray)->()) {
        let companyArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
        let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/Companies/JSON.php")!
        let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                do{
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)
                    if let companies = json["companies"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                        for company in companies {
                            if let name = company["name"] as? String,
                                let phoneNumber = company["phone_number"] as? String,
                                let website = company["website"] as? String,
                                let email = company["email"] as? String,
                                let address = company["address"] as? String {
                                let company = CompanyModel()
                                company.name = name
                                company.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
                                company.website = website
                                company.email = email
                                company.address = address
                                companyArray.addObject(company)
                            }
                        }

                        // CALLBACK HERE
                        completion(array: companyArray)

                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error with Json: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Now to get the array from the network we use a trailing closure like this:

```
getJSON { (array) in
    print(array)
}
```